# Take photo in android ARToolkit

Tags: android, augmented-reality, artoolkit, android-augmented-reality

How can I take a photo with 3d model using android ARToolkit library? I didn't find a solution in official documentation or examples.

Comment: Do you mean you want to take a screenshot of what is shown on the screen, camera and you graphics?

Comment: @yakobom screenshot is one of the options. I tried to make screenshot of frame layout through drawing cache but no effect, image is empty

Comment: Perhaps you can do it via OpenGL - using GLES20.glReadPixels and write the data into a bitmap. Is that an option for you?

Comment: Anyway, I suggest you do post the code that you have tried, so people can try to help you out

Answer (score 0):

There are answers here which show taking an image of just your Application, but this would include any GUI etc..
[How to programmatically take a screenshot in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programmatically-take-a-screenshot-in-android)